# creating a basic sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint

if i want to create a basic sharepoint site. do i need a sharepoint designer ? or some other sharepoint software ?

Answer (score 3):

Just start with SharePoint.  Don't do anything with SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio until you understand what SharePoint really is and what it can do.  SharePoint has a ton of features, and it takes some time to understand its strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you meant by **create***. If you want to customize site look and feel then you need to use SharePoint designer. If you just need to create a site you don't need to use any tools or other specific software. By default SharePoint has builtin support to create sites.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd just need the [WSS 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SharePoint_Services) piece; which is free but which needs a "Server" OS. Won't run on XP/Vista.

To make complex sites: you'd need a programming environment like VS with the Designer plugins/addins to create web parts etc.
To use advanced features like document integration, search, etc. you'd need to buy the [MOSS 07](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_Server) piece of Sharepoint.